# Timestamps %in% timestamps unexpected results

Tags: r

I am trying to compare two arrays of timestamps. When I use the `%in%` operand, result are `False` while it should be `true`. When I cast them to `numerics`, the results are as expected.

Any ideas why this is so?

```
fetchedTimestamps = c("30-1-2016 10:00:00", "30-1-2016 10:15:00", "30-1-2016 10:45:00")
fetchedTimestamps = strptime(fetchedTimestamps, format = "%d-%m-%Y %X")
# [1] "2016-01-30 10:00:00 CET" "2016-01-30 10:15:00 CET" "2016-01-30 10:45:00 CET"

expectedTimestamps = seq(min(fetchedTimestamps), max(fetchedTimestamps), by = "15 mins")
# [1] "2016-01-30 10:00:00 CET" "2016-01-30 10:15:00 CET" "2016-01-30 10:30:00 CET" "2016-01-30 10:45:00 CET"


expectedTimestamps %in% fetchedTimestamps
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

as.numeric(expectedTimestamps) %in% as.numeric(fetchedTimestamps)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare `class(fetchedTimestamps[1])` and `class(expectedTimestamps[1])`, they differ, which could be leading to the non-equality. One is `POSIXct`, the other `POSIXlt` (see https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html). By converting both to `numeric`, you now have comparable objects.

Comment: Thats it.. Thanks Benjamin!